# Triangle with points on perimeter of circle, python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to make a triangle with 3 random points on perimeter of a circle, that has random center coordinates x and y (random_x and random_y in the code). It takes radius as an input from user. And the circle can not be cut from any side (this is working).

**What I am trying to figure out now is**, how to put `"."` on perimeter of the circle.(Just a mid step for myself to see if it is on a perimeter)

From there I will move to the lines of triangle, but I need to figure this out first. Maybe there is just a math mistake in my code or just some stupid thing:

```
import tkinter, random, math

g = tkinter.Canvas(width=500, height=500)
g.pack()

radius = int(input("enter radius: "))

#generating random coordinates x and y, center of the circle
#"radius," and "-radius" are there so circle isn't out of canvas
random_x = random.randint(radius,500 - radius)
random_y = random.randint(radius,500 - radius)

#actual coordinates of Circle (Oval)
x1 = random_x - radius
y1 = random_y - radius

x2 = random_x + radius
y2 = random_y + radius

g.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='red')
# fill red is not neccessary

full_circle=2*math.pi
#random.uniform used because of floats ?
random_pi = random.uniform(0, full_circle)

point1 = random_x + (radius * math.cos(random_pi))
point2 = random_y + (radius * math.cos(random_pi))

#this "." is just to check if it is on perimeter of a circle
g.create_text(point1,point2,text=".")

#those prints are here just for check
print("random_x: ", random_x)
print("random_y: ", random_y)
print("radius: ", radius)
print("point1: ", point1)
print("point2: ", point2)
```

Comment: What's your question / problem?

Comment: I believe the provided answer is what you are looking for. Further Clarification if it is not would be nice :)

Comment: @Matis are you sure to have to put a **TypeSetting character( <_dot_> ) onto a pixmap** with a Circle object? Your text sounds, you have other task with these pre-conditions set: **[a] generate a CIRCLE** that has a random Centre_POINT, but such, that is farther than a Radius_DISTANCE from each of the Painting_AREA edges, **[b] generate a TRIANGLE** that has all it's Vertex POINTs on the perimeter of such a Circle meeting [a] (meaning: generate a set of three disjunct random angles Phi1, Phi2, Phi3, used in for Polar Coordinates ( R, Phi ) with centre [0,0] translated by [Circle.x, Circle.y] )

Comment: @user3666197 The dot was there as a help for myself, to see if it is on a perimeter, If i had that right I would move on from there to creating lines into triangle. Dot was just a mid step. **Thanks to the Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams he is right the other one should be** sin()

Comment: @Matis You might have realised by your own that with the use of **Polar Coordinate System** ( R, Phi ), shifted ( translated ) correctly in 2D by a vector of [X,Y] ( an offset of the Circle centre ), **ANY point ( const( R_circle ), var( Phi ) ) has no other chance but to be right on the Circle perimeter** ( if it is not, there is either an error in the code, or some rare precision / rounding artifact, but not larger than a 1-pixel in x-direction and/or y-direction, due to which the both lines of the triangle associated with this point will have to "suffer from" in the exactly same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

> ```
> point1 = random_x + (radius * math.cos(random_pi))
> point2 = random_y + (radius * math.cos(random_pi))
> ```

One should be `cos()`, the other `sin()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a couple of ways you can do this in tkinter, you could use a label or I would use an image as a label, but that's up to you.

To get the label where you want it, you can use `.place(x=..., y=...)` given that you have the coordinates of the spot. This will mean you should change the existing `.pack()` to `.place()` as well.

`.place` aligns to the top left of the label. fyi

Have noticed now that another person has given an answer which is probably the best solution, but i thought i might as well add my ten cents worth :).

Answer (score -1):

*If what you are trying to do is to [draw a dot in tkinter, then this link will assist](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2839)*

## **My Solution from [Link Provided](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2839)**

[Draw a 1 line pixel to represent your dot](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_canvas.htm).

You already have your coordinates at `point1` and `point2`, so this is as easy as:

```
line = canvas.create_line(point1, point2, point1+1, point2+1)
```

Comment: a `.` is not a valid name in Python.

Comment: @AaronHall, feedback would be nice, as the downvote was harsh :)

Comment: I think because you answered strangely by writing why `.` isn't a valid name, which didn't really have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @W1ll1amvl, That was due to a misunderstanding of previous notes. I now omitted it, and left the part that is correct.

Comment: Your answer would be better if it didn't rely on an external link. As soon as that link goes down, your answer becomes useless. Could you add actual working code to your answer?